# A function for batch backpropagation of weight errors in a dense neural network layer

Tags: rust, neural-network

I'm switching my neural network library over to using [ArrayFire](https://arrayfire.com/) for performance.

One of the features I am losing moving from [ndarray](https://lib.rs/crates/ndarray) is [ndarray_einsum_beta](https://lib.rs/crates/ndarray_einsum_beta), as such I need to write my own function to carry out what I was using einsum for.

This function needs to be as fast as possible.

This is the function:

```
fn arrayfire_weight_errors(errors:arrayfire::Array<f32>,activations:arrayfire::Array<f32>) -> arrayfire::Array<f32> {
    let rows:u64 = errors.dims().get()[0];

    let er_width:u64 = errors.dims().get()[1];
    let act_width:u64 = activations.dims().get()[1];
    let dims = arrayfire::Dim4::new(&[act_width,er_width,rows,1]);

    let temp:arrayfire::Array<f32> = arrayfire::Array::<f32>::new_empty(dims);

    for i in 0..rows {
        let holder = arrayfire::matmul(
            &arrayfire::row(&activations,i),
            &arrayfire::row(&errors,i),
            arrayfire::MatProp::TRANS,
            arrayfire::MatProp::NONE
        );
        arrayfire::set_slice(&temp,&holder,i);
    }
    return temp
}
```

How could I improve this to make it better? (and hopefully faster)

(Apologies for using `arrayfire::` everywhere, this is a test project which uses a few other linear algebra libraries, so it's best to specify)

ndarray approach:

```
fn ndarray_einsum(errors:ndarray::Array2<f32>,activations:ndarray::Array2<f32>) -> ndarray::ArrayD<f32> {
    return ndarray_einsum_beta::einsum("ai,aj->aji", &[&errors, &activations]).unwrap();
}
```